# Possible to add an `app` method through middleware in Express?

Tags: express, middleware

I am trying to write a middleware that creates a new method on `app` created with `express()`. For example, I would like to achieve the following:

```
app.use(myMiddleware())
// ...
app.newMethod() // added through the previous middleware
```

Is there a way to achieve this? A way I have thought of, as referenced in some other questions, is to pass in `app` itself as a param to my middleware so that I could tweak it:

```
app.use(myMiddleware(app))
// ...
app.newMethod() // ok, definitely doable
```

However, this does not seem elegant enough.
Also, `req.app` and `res.app` references won't work for me in this case, since the `(req, res, next) => {}` function returned by `myMiddleware()` only executes when receiving requests, while I possibly want to access the method before even `app.listen()` is called.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't make sense to add an `app` method in middleware.  The purpose of middleware is to process an incoming request, either in preparation for later middleware or later request handlers or to just handle the request itself in the middleware.

Middleware gets called over and over during incoming requests.  It should never be used for something that should just happen once and it should only be used for processing related to an incoming request.

> while I possibly want to access the method before even app.listen() is called

So, that definitely has nothing to do with an incoming request then so using middleware is just not the right design choice.

If all you're trying to do is to add your own method to the `app` object, you can do that when you are initializing your server:

```
const app = require('express')();

// add my own method to the app object
app.myMethod = function(myArg1, myArg2)  {
    // put the implementation here
}

app.use(...);
app.get(...);
app.get(...);

app.listen(...);
```

Then, anywhere you want, you can call `app.myMethod(...)`.